# Error while generating a UI5 project using "generator-easy-ui5" in CLI

Tags: node.js, sapui5, node-modules, yeoman

While I am performing the steps according to the tutorial
[Create an App for SAP Build Work Zone, standard edition](https://developers.sap.com/tutorials/sapui5-fiori-cf-create-project.html), it throws the following error:

[image: Error Image In Command Prompt]

I tried to execute by following the steps but can't proceed because of the error.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** the issue has been fixed since [ui5-community/generator-ui5-project commit `5704766`](https://github.com/ui5-community/generator-ui5-project/commit/5704766a0590c77a76701a17b330e028fcf8bb7e), making UI5 content generation (e.g. `yo easy-ui5 project`) compatible with Node.js v**18**.

Simply run `npm install -g yo generator-easy-ui5` to upgrade the `easy-ui5` generator.

---

**Previous answer:**

This is a known issue. See https://github.com/SAP/generator-easy-ui5/issues/105.

Your Node.js version is currently too high.

Since you're on Windows, try [nvm-windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows) to switch between different Node.js versions. Installing and using Node.js v16 should resolve the issue for now.